# Having trouble executing JS script called in external file

Tags: javascript, html

I'm sure that I'm missing something really obvious here, but just not seeing it.  I have some js code to obscure an email link on my website.  When the code is embedded in the original web page (within  tags, etc), then everything performs as it should.  Here is the code as it appears within my web page:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" >
<!--
var part1 = "et";
var part2 = "hoto";
var part3 = "comc";
var part4 = "MASP";
var part5 = "ast.n";
var part6 = "PDX";
document.write('<a href="mai' + 'lto:' + part4 + part2 + part6 + '@' + part3 + part5 + part1 + '">');
document.write('<img src="images/ContactLink-clear.png" style="border-style: none" height="100px" width="300px" alt="Contact Info"  title="Contact Info" /></a>');
// -->
</script>
```

However, when I take this same code and paste it into a js file, and call it using:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="link.js"></script>
```

then I get a broken link... interestingly, the mail to appears to function, so I am thinking something wrong with the execution of the  tag, but I am not seeing it.  Just for completeness, the code within the js file is:

```
var part1 = "et";
var part2 = "hoto";
var part3 = "comc";
var part4 = "MASP";
var part5 = "ast.n";
var part6 = "PDX";
document.write('<a href="mai' + 'lto:' + part4 + part2 + part6 + '@' + part3 + part5 + part1 + '">');
document.write('<img src="images/ContactLink-clear.png" style="border-style: none" height="100px" width="300px" alt="Contact Info"  title="Contact Info" /></a>');
```

Any thoughts or creative suggestions?  Thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: Are you afraid of getting spammed? This isn't an effective countermeasure. Page scrapers these days run JS on the page.

Comment: you can easily check by opening your development tool on your browser.  First see if link.js is loaded and then you can use breakpoints to debug..

Comment: What do you mean by a broken link, if the mailto works then its not exactly broken. Another thought would be to not use document.write, use DOM functions like `createElement()` and `appendChild()`

Comment: by broken link, I mean that the image associated with the 'mailto:' link did not load.  The mailto functionality seems to be just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can put you code inside a function like this one:

```
function obscureMail() {
    var part1 = "et";
    var part2 = "hoto";
    var part3 = "comc";
    var part4 = "MASP";
    var part5 = "ast.n";
    var part6 = "PDX";
    document.write('<a href="mai' + 'lto:' + part4 + part2 + part6 + '@' + part3 + part5 + part1 + '">');
    document.write('<img src="images/ContactLink-clear.png" style="border-style: none" height="100px" width="300px" alt="Contact Info"  title="Contact Info" /></a>');
}
```

and then add a call in your body tag like:

```
<body onload="obscureMail()">
```

Comment: That would be a good way to go, but I need the code to drop in and function within a particular location on the page... div container

Comment: Basically, I am trying to create a hotlink on my page associated with an image, and place it into a particular location

Comment: I should point out that I am trying to do this in order to minimize script calls (which google doesn't appear to like to see more than one of per page), and I have to call another js file to set up some function calls for a jquery slide show later on.  So, I thought it would be nice if I could combine everything in one js call... not working out so well...